# Does reference variable take memory in stack?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int main()
{
   int a=45;
   int& re=a;
   cout << &a << endl;
   cout << &re << endl;
   return 0;
}

 Output :
   0x61ff18
   0x61ff18
```

When i print address of both variable its same , Is it means reference variable does not take memory in stack ?

Comment: hard to say, because the existence of stack itself is implementation defined.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846494/do-references-take-memory-in-c)

Comment: It might have been optimized away (although generally yes it does take memory)

Comment: @user3528438: Re "the existence of stack itself is implementation defined", where did you pick up that meme? It's nonsense.

Comment: The names "a" and "re" refer to the same object. You're printing the address of this object in both cases. (And it's very likely that the only reason that the object has an address at all is that you're printing it.)

Comment: @Alf the concept of stack variable has been formalized to "automatic storage duration" and "temporary storage duration" a long time ago, stack has been an implementation detail every since. if you look at the standard, nothing enforces the existence of stack, although it's a popular way of implementing what needs to be implemented.

Comment: @user3528438: The C++ standard requires a stack because C++ functions can be recursive. Things like stack unwinding don't make sense without a stack. So I'm sorry but what you write is pure nonsense. I won't use the "i" word but it's lurking in the background here. I think this meme is possibly tied up with a too restrictive interpretation of the word "stack", but it doesn't matter so much: it's just nonsense.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf C's function is also recursive, but there's no single word of "stack" in the current C standard. Also C++'s definition of stack unwinding is not tied to the definition of stack, either. Just like heap is one way of implementing dynamic memory allocation, stack is just one way of implementing some features the standard requires. The standard is abstract. Is it feasible to implement C++ without using stack? I don't know; I don't know who knows, either; and I don't care; and I believe nobody cares, either.

Comment: @user3528438: You're still talking nonsense. Also known as rubbish. It misleads learners in an ungood direction, so please help stop that meme. Please note that just the notion of "without a stack" is nonsense. That is, it does make sense, it has no meaning, it's idiocy.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Well, since this discussion is becoming subjective, I won't say anything further.

Comment: User @user3528438's claim that he or she is objective while spouting out nonsense, and that it's subjective to point out that it's nonsense, is, well, nonsense; appeal-to-emotions nonsense but still nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

address-of operator of the reference in C++ gives you address of the referenced object - not the address of reference variable itself. By C++ specification.

Therefore you see the same value.

Comment: So how can i print address of reference variable itself ?

Comment: @shuboy2014 You can't. The language provides no facility for this.

Comment: @shuboy2014 reference is an alias and may have no storage at all.

Answer (score 2):

`&` takes the address of the referenced object, not of the reference itself, hence the output is the same for both `&a` and `&re`. In typical implementations, references themselves do require memory unless optimised away. Consult your implementation's documentation and its assembly output (`-S` flag for GCC and clang). The language specification gives no guarantees.